# How to automatically insert a string after the prompt

Tags: bash, command-line, prompt

I have a `bash` terminal window where I execute **exclusively** one command `foo`. Because of that I'd like every line (after the prompt of course) to begin with „foo ” so that I just have to type the functions' options and arguments, but not the recurrent function name. Of course it would be nice to be able to alter the automatically inserted string too, but that's **not essential** for me.

#### Example

When I open the terminal, without typing anything what I want to see is:

```
user@host:~/ $ foo
```

Then I type `--option argument` and when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> the function `foo` is called with the given `--option` and `argument`.

#### What I tried

I tried to fiddle around with `$PS1` and `$PROMPT_COMMAND` using `xdotool type "foo "` and astonishingly that actually works, but unfortunately it also prints “foo ” **before** the prompt, which is quite ugly:

```
user@host:~/ $ PROMPT_COMMAND='xdotool type "foo "'
foo user@host:~/ $ foo
```

I also found and tried the `preexec` function from [Ryan Caloras' bash-preexec script](https://github.com/rcaloras/bash-preexec), but it has exactly the same problem.

[How to echo (a (executable-)string) to the prompt, so that the cursor flashes at the end of the line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/50338/246819) is related, but the answers there don't make it possible to add something (`--option argument`) to the command to be executed. I didn't test `zsh` though – there ought to be a `bash` solution for such a simple thing, don't you think?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/5363/how-to-start-a-terminal-with-certain-text-already-input-on-the-command-line,

Comment: @muru I tested `expect`, but it doesn't enter the text on every prompt, but only at the first one. While that's wanted in the linked question, my goal is different.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `zsh`, it should just be a matter of:

```
precmd() print -z 'foo '
```

Or to avoid it overriding commands queued by the user with <kbd>Alt+q</kbd>:

```
zle-line-init() { [ -n "$BUFFER" ] || LBUFFER='foo '; }
zle -N zle-line-init
```

With `bash`, instead of `xdotool`, you could  use the `TIOCSTI` `ioctl`:

```
insert() {
  perl -le 'require "sys/ioctl.ph";
            ioctl(STDIN, &TIOCSTI, $_) for split "", join " ", @ARGV' -- "$@"
}
PROMPT_COMMAND='insert "foo "'
```

It's preferable to `xdotool` because it's inserting those characters directly in the input buffer of the device `bash` is reading from. `xdotool` would only work if there's a X server running (wouldn't work on the console or real terminals or over `ssh` (without `-X`) for instance), that it is the one identified by `$DISPLAY` and that's the one you're interacting with, and that the terminal emulator `bash` is running in has the focus when `$PROMPT_COMMAND` is evaluated.

Now, like in your `xdotool` case, because the `ioctl()` is done before the prompt is displayed and the tty terminal line discipline is put out of `icanon+echo` mode by readline, you're likely to see the *echo* of that `foo` by the tty line discipline messing up the display.

You could work around that by instead inserting a string whose *echo* is invisible (like U+200B if using exclusively Unicode locales) and bind that to an action that inserts `"foo "`:

```
insert() {
  perl -le 'require "sys/ioctl.ph";
            ioctl(STDIN, &TIOCSTI, $_) for split "", join " ", @ARGV' -- "$@"
}
bind $'"\u200b":"foo "'
PROMPT_COMMAND="insert $'\u200b'"
```

Or you could delay the `TIOCSTI` ioctl enough for readline to have time to initialise:

```
insert_with_delay() {
  perl -le 'require "sys/ioctl.ph";
            $delay = shift @ARGV;
            unless(fork) {
              select undef, undef, undef, $delay;
              ioctl(STDIN, &TIOCSTI, $_) for split "", join " ", @ARGV;
            }' -- "$@";
}
PROMPT_COMMAND='insert_with_delay 0.05 "foo "'
```

If, like in the `zsh` approaches, you want to handle the case where the user enters text before the prompt is displayed, you could either

- *drain* that by doing a `tcflush(0, TCIFLUSH)` in `perl` before the `TIOCSTI` ioctl (also needs a `-MPOSIX` option), or
- like in the `zsh` approach, ensure the `foo` is inserted at the start of the buffer by inserting a `^A` (assuming you use the `emacs` (default) editing mode where that moves the cursor to  the beginning of the line) before `foo` and `^E` after (to move to the end):

  ```
  insert_with_delay 0.05 $'\1foo \5'
  ```

  or

  ```
  bind $'"\u200b":"\1foo \5"'
  ```

Comment: The `insert` function needs a bit of work to properly quote arguments that require quoting. Perhaps with `perl ... -- "$(printf "%q " "$@")"`

Comment: Hi @glenn. Not sure what you mean. Here we want to insert `foo ` or a U+200B character, not `'foo '`

Comment: Perhaps I'm over-complicating matters. I was thinking of the case where the pre-populated text would be like `foo "bar baz" ` where the 2nd argument needs to be quoted.

Comment: @glennjackman, I'd say that has to  be taken care of by the caller. `insert` here is meant to get shell code as argument (like `eval`) so you can call it  with `insert 'VAR="x y" cmd2 '` or `insert 'cmd "${default_opt[@]}" '` for instance which you couldn't do if `insert` was quoting  its arguments by itself.

Comment: I used your astonishing approach in this Ask Ubuntu question, where the problem originally was raised: [Main Terminal Window Displaying Commands Only](https://askubuntu.com/questions/954051/)

Comment: By a couple of months in this case. (-:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/111974/5132

Answer (score 4):

What you're asking for doesn't sound very common so it isn't surprising that there isn't a straightforward way to do it.

With pure bash, you can use the `read` builtin to read the line, then `eval` to execute it. Simulate the prompt (I'm approximating your prompt below).

```
#!/bin/bash    
PROMPT=$'\e[1m'$USER@$HOSTNAME:$PWD$' $ \e[0m'
IFS= read -r -e -i "foo " -p "$PROMPT" line
eval "$line"
exit
```

Put this in a script and tell your terminal emulator to run that script.

Alternatively, run Screen in the terminal emulator. You can use its `stuff` command to simulate input.