# Command to inject string into command line, like a pre-filled command to edit before execution

Tags: bash, command-line

With `$` as my bash prompt and `⏎` symbolizing me hitting the enter key in the following example, how could I construct a command/alias `foo` so that

```
$ foo bar⏎
```

would enter/input/pre-fill/type "bar" (or any other string I pass to the command) to the command line, so that I can modify "bar" before hitting Enter? E.g.

```
$ bar
…
$ barbaz⏎
```

I've unsuccessfully tried `echo bar > /dev/pts/123` and would like to do without `xdotool`. Is this possible?

---

EDIT: Example use case, a "greppy autocomplete":

I often need long commands with many arguments that are hard to remember. I keep examples in a file:

commands.txt:

```
ffmpeg -i infile.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a copy -y transcoded.mp4
sox in.wav out.wav remix 1 0
```

now, if I had the command as specified above, let's call it `inject`, I could have an alias

```
grepcomplete () {
  inject $(grep $0 commands.txt)
}
```

so when I remember that I need to *remix* something, but I don't remember *sox* and its arguments, I can type `grepcomplete remix`, and then have `sox in.wav out.wav remix 1 0` sit on my command line, as if I typed it out, ready for me to edit and adapt, before I execute it by hitting enter.
Without the need to select, copy, paste anything.

As Kamil suggests in the comments, I could use bash's history search (Ctrl-R), and provide my own "history" by doing something like `history -r commands.txt` in my bashrc.
Still, my approach has the benefit that I can easily hack it, e.g. by displaying all matches with syntax highlighting.

Please note that I've answered this question myself, where I provide an implementation of this `inject` command.

Comment: If this is to edit the output of a command or the value of a variable before you actually use it in another command, bash and zsh have keybindings that can expand all variable expansions, command substitutions, etc. That might be simpler than hacking your way around terminal input.

Comment: What is the usage case? I mean *typing* `foo bar` only to get `bar` in the command line clearly takes *more* effort than simply typing `bar` in the first place. Therefore I guess you want to use this `foo` in some other way. How exactly? Your question is remotely similar to [this one](https://superuser.com/q/1494061/432690), where the gain in effort is indisputable.

Comment: @muru very true, I've played around with bash's ctrl+alt+e/C-M-e, but it wasn't quite right for my (slightly odd) workflow.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski of course this is just a building block & for the examples there is no gain in efficiency. The actual use case is a "completion/pre-fill with grep" for my most-used "commands that need adjustment", e.g. `snippet remix` will enter `sox in.wav out.wav remix 1 0 # upmix mono to stereo` into the prompt for me to edit and execute, without the need to select, copy, paste.  
Still I find this sub-problem worthwhile exploring without the context.

Comment: An idea: a history file that holds your most-used "commands that need adjustment"; then Ctrl+R.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski yes, that's what I've implemented in the end. I was aware of bash's history search but I never liked its UX. But now I've just learned about `history -r`, if I do that in bashrc, hmm... thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a small and ugly solution, inspired [by a perl solution to insert a string after each prompt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/391679/how-to-automatically-insert-a-string-after-the-prompt), using TIOCSTI [adapted to python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29615101/629238):

A bash function, e.g. for `.bashrc`

```bash
inject () {
(python -c "import fcntl; import termios; import sys
with open('/dev/stdout', 'w') as fd:
  for c in ' '.join(sys.argv[1:]): fcntl.ioctl(fd, termios.TIOCSTI, c)" "$@" &)
}
```

Usage:

```bash
inject foo bar
```

Notes:

- can't handle Unicode at the moment! I suspect the `for char in str` is to blame?
- The background-in-subshell construct `( foo &)` [prevents double-echo'ing the string before the prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686989/running-bash-commands-in-the-background-without-printing-job-and-process-ids/7687722#7687722)
- It will eat whitespace between arguments: `inject foo    bar` = `inject foo bar`. Use `inject "foo   bar"`.
- It looks like it depends on timing, so race conditions might arise?
- I had other versions with Python's threads/multiprocessing that can do without the bash subshell and might work better for piping, xargs etc. This was the cleanest and simplest solution for my use case.

Comment: Works great if you just want a Python program to be able to inject something to the outer Bash prompt.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure this using `~/.inputrc`. Create the file if it doesn't exist, and add this:

```
Control-P: "foo "
```

Now, open a new terminal and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and the string `foo` will be entered where your cursor is. You can choose a shortcut that works for you, and it should work.

Comment: Cool, thanks! But I need the string to be dynamic, hence I take it as an argument.

Comment: Oh. In that case, @kubi, please edit your question and clarify that because it isn't mentioned anywhere. You only ask for a command to insert a specific string. How would you define this string then and if you need to define it, why not just type it out on the command line?

Comment: Sorry! I felt like if I give `bar` as an argument, it would be self-explanatory that this is not a constant. (Any of the other answers were confused by this, FWIW.). I'm not sure I get your question about "defining" it, I want to be able do something like `grep bar commands.txt | xargs foo`, or `bar=baz foo $bar`... have you seen *my own* answer?

Comment: @kubi I may be dense, but I still don't get it. You are writing `inject foo bar` which is more work than just writing `foo bar` directly. If you always need to write out what you are "injecting" then why not just write it out? If you want to run specific commands more easily, then you would write a function like `run foo file1` that would run say `grep foo file1 | head -9 | wc` or whatever. But that's just a trivial little function, no need for a whole python import. Please edit your question and give a use case so we can understand what you need.

Comment: I've edited the question to provide an example use case. Does that clear it up? Please also note that my own answer already works for me. I guess I should have accepted it? I was curious if there were better solutions. I'm sorry if I have wasted anybody's time.

Comment: Yes, thank you, @kubi, that makes it much clearer! I will delete this answer in a bit since it doesn't solve your issue at all. As for accepting, it is completely up to you. You can accept your own answer, yes, or another one if that works better. Just accept whichever one you end up using.

Answer (score 0):

`xdotool` will only work in X environment, and won't work in the TTY shell and may not work in Wayland.

---

I feel like you are asking about [creating your own bash completion script](https://opensource.com/article/18/3/creating-bash-completion-script). Then, "inject" (invoke the completion) with `Tab` key.

The basic idea is this `complete` command which says to bash what to suggest when user hits `Tab` key:

```
$ complete -W "now tomorrow never" dothis
```

Then, typing

```
$ dothis to<Tab>
```

fills it:

```
$ dothis tomorrow
```

For your example,

```bash
$ complete -W bar foo
$ foo<Space><Tab>
```

will produce

```
$ foo bar
```

Which you can edit futher.

The `complete` command itself could be placed into `~/.bashrc` to be run during interactive shell creation.

Comment: I sort of am, yes :) and I have finished it. It's very specific to my workflow, but I still found this sub-problem interesting.  
And as you can see in my answer, I managed without `xdotool` -- your warning was exactly why I asked to avoid it.  
But thank you for your contribution, it will definitely help with future iterations of my setup!

Answer (score 0):

If switching to `zsh` is an option, then it's just:

```
print -rz -- "$text"
```

To seed zsh's line editor (zle) with the given text.

If done within a custom zle widget, you'd do:

```
LBUFFER+=$text
```

to insert the text at the cursor, or:

```
BUFFER+=$text
```

To insert at the end, or:

```
BUFFER[n,0]=$text
```

To insert it before the `n`<sup>th</sup> character in the editing buffer.

So

```
BUFFER[CURSOR+1,0]=$text
```

Would insert the text at the cursor without moving the cursor position, same as:

```
RBUFFER[1,0]=$text
```

With:

- `$BUFFER`: full editing buffer
- `$CURSOR`: current cursor position inside that buffer (0 at the start)
- `$LBUFFER`/`$RBUFFER`: for convenience the portion of `$BUFFER` left and right of the cursor respectively.

See `info zsh widgets` for details.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I've been comtemplating abandoning bash for years...

Answer (score 0):

In fish the equivalent is using the `commandline` function. For example:

```
commandline 'echo next command'
```